# How to change Div width by pressing a button in asp.net C#

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

I have a div which I use as a left panel. But when I press a button, the width of the div goes from e.g. 250px to 50px.

Something like this:
[image: pic1]

and when press the top button. the size goes to this:
[image: pic2]
NOTE: the pics are from a website. I dont own them.

when click the button the top icon (next to the button disappears) and the size of the width goes to lower, just enough to show the icons..

I know its not good to make a post without code. but I dont know even where to start with this. I searched on google but nothing so far.

EDIT: disappearing the icon on top is not really important. but the text "welcome, mr admin" yes. and I have the button icon, just need the button function

Comment: Do you want to do this server side or client side? If server side, are you using web forms, MVC, WebPages? If client side are you open to using jquery?

Comment: but whats the difference between those two? I am trying to build this only in asp.net and c# no other

Comment: Normally you'd do this kind of action clientside using javascript (and maybe with a little CSS). You can certainly do it serverside, the methodology will change depending on wether you are using WebForms, MVC or some other varient of ASP.net

Comment: Im using WebForms, but if I make it in server side. when someone will click that button, will it change to all other websites open? does it work like that?

Comment: Unless you handle the menu state yourself, the change will be for that page on that view only and only for that user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hamburger menu is best implemented with [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/). The server (ASP.NET/C#) is not involved with this.

If you don't use Bootstrap... better do. Menus like these are nearly always implemented with it.

Comment: hey, I also had a question, I want to set a list of buttons in the same width with each other.. but I am using CssClass="buttonwidth". I know this works well, but I once read for something which when you enter button there, it automatically sets the width and under the button above. I am trying to find it. should I make this with bootstrap too?

Comment: Ummm... there are many examples of "Hamburger" implementations that don't use Bootstap. That being said I also don't believe that the menu is actually the issue at hand.

Comment: @JonP I remember it was somekind like a list. still dont remember where I rad it or how to find it again.